# How to bring back the value to default of text area?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, drop-down-menu, textbox

I have code here that if the checkbox is checked, it will multiply the value of the checkbox and the value of the dropdown list and will display product to the text area. My problem is even if the checkbox is not check, when you change the value of the dropbox it still execute the operation and display the product of the values. And also if I unchecked the checkbox, it doesn't bring back the value of the text area to 0. Below is the code

```
<table align=center border=1>
    <tr colspan=3>
        <td colspan=3><h2>Specialty Cakes</h2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><center><img src=special\blackforest_small.jpg ><br>Black Forest</center></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check1" value="550.00"onclick="special1()">Buy P550.00</input><br><input type="text" id="total1" name="total1" value="P0.00"size="8"></input><br>
        QTY: <select id="qty1" name="qty1" onchange="special1()">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    function special1(){
        var m = document.getElementById("check1").checked;
        var x = document.getElementById("check1").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("qty1").value;
        var z = 0;
        if (m = true){
            z = "P" + x * y;
        }
        document.getElementById("total1").value = z;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You should use `==` or `===` for comparison not `=`. Also there is no `textarea` element in your markup and `input` is a _void_ element, it doesn't have closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change this

```
if (m = true){
z = "P" + x * y;
}
```

to like below

```
if (m == true){
z = "P" + x * y;
}
```

you should use "==" operator for comparison

Comment: Its always good to explain answers; it may be obvious to us, but it isn't always obvious to them.